# How to scan for user input of both strings and ints to put into a 2D array in c

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am writing a program in C on 2D arrays where I am to get a user generated 2d array based off the amount of employees and products in the store. I am having trouble figuring out how to get the user input consisting of both names and numbers into the array.

```
  for (int r = 0; r < employees; r++)
{
   for (int c = 0;c < numProducts; c++)
    {
        arr[r][c] = getUserInput();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you describe this in a bit more detail? What is the return value of the `getUserInput` function. Example input and outputs would be also helpful.

Comment: @Eraklon The user input is employee names and their sales of each product.  Such as "Jim" $43 $500 $878 for the amount he sold of each product
                                                                                                                                  printf("Please enter no. of salesmen: \n");
    employees = getUserInput();

    printf("Please enter no. of products: \n");
    numProducts = getUserInput();

Answer (score 1):

So you can use a vector of pairs witch can contain `string`s and `int`s.

This sample program allows you to enter pairs node by node, and stores it in a vector of pairs (`string` and `int`):

[**Live sample**](https://onlinegdb.com/rJ6jz_xQ8)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{    
    int num;
    std::string str;
    std::vector<std::pair<std::string, int>> nodes; //container

    std::cout << "Enter string and number" << std::endl;
    while(std::cin >> str)
    {
        if(str == "exit") //type exit to leave the input cycle
           break;
        std::cin >> num;
        nodes.push_back(std::make_pair(str, num));
    }

    for (const auto& p : nodes)  // print the products
    {
        std::cout << p.first << " " << p.second << std::endl;  
    }
}
```

You now can incorporate it in what you need to do since your description of the problem doesn't allow me to understand exactly how you relate employees with products and names.

**EDIT**

So based on you coment I added a new solution maintaining `std::pair` it's very esasy to use and I'm sure no one will complain about it, so you need a container that has pairs (name, vector of values).

I separated the input of names and values because you you have an employee with several names it's harder to manage the input.

There is no number of employees and products, you can put as many as you need with as many product values as you need.

[**Live sample**](https://onlinegdb.com/Sy7RKwWmU)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

int main() {
    double temp_num;
    std::string str, name;
    std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::vector<double>>> nodes;  //container
    std::vector<double> values;
    while(true){
        std::cout << "Enter employee name ('exit' to leave): ";
        getline(std::cin, str);  //employee name
        if (str == "exit") {
            break;
        }
        name = str;
        std::cout << "Enter values: ";
        getline(std::cin, str);  //values
        std::stringstream ss(str);
        while(ss >> temp_num)
            values.push_back(temp_num);       
        nodes.push_back(std::make_pair(name, values));
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    for (const auto& p : nodes)  // print names and the products
    {
        std::cout <<"Name - " << p.first << ": ";
        for (const auto& vals : p.second) {
            std::cout <<"$"<< vals << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I haven't learned of vector of pairs yet. The relationship is the user will input each employee followed by the dollar amount of each product they sold. So the user starts by telling the amount of employees and how many products ie 3 employees 2 products then i am to get the specific information and calculate total sales

Comment: @AspiringProgrammer19 I added a possible solution, these data structures are more simple than they look at first glance.